# Error when trying to run a meteor app in docker using meteorhacks:meteord

Tags: meteor, docker

I have just began playing around with docker. While trying out method 1 from [meteorhacks:meteord](https://github.com/meteorhacks/meteord), I get the folowing error

```
=> You don't have an meteor app to run in this image.
```

Here is what I have done after creating the basic counter demo meteor app.

```
 docker build -t app .
Sending build context to Docker daemon 11.75 MB
Step 0 : FROM meteorhacks/meteord:base
 ---> 528baf8d4263
Step 1 : MAINTAINER MeteorHacks Pvt Ltd.
 ---> Running in 6d7e7eb6ebce
 ---> d69fefdbeb70
Removing intermediate container 6d7e7eb6ebce
Step 2 : ONBUILD copy ./ /app
 ---> Running in e68618104dfa
 ---> c253ae966ea1
Removing intermediate container e68618104dfa
Step 3 : ONBUILD run bash $METEORD_DIR/on_build.sh
 ---> Running in e51e557c2b05
 ---> a6a6a1be9147
Removing intermediate container e51e557c2b05
Successfully built a6a6a1be9147
```

then ( I already initiated a mongo container exposing 27017 and grabbed the internal ip  address which was  171.17.0.1)

```
docker run -d \
    -e ROOT_URL=http://localhost:3000 \
    -e MONGO_URL=mongodb://172.17.0.1:27017/ \
    -e MONGO_OPLOG_URL=mongodb://172.17.0.1:27017/ \
    -p 8080:80 \
    app
```

I get the error when I do this and then run `docker logs <container id>`

Can someone guide me on this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

This error comes from [`scripts/run_app.sh`](https://github.com/meteorhacks/meteord/blob/c3b448d43fa5d741a811c02600a95173b0c7d26d/base/scripts/run_app.sh#L3-L20), which is the [`ENTRYPOINT` of the base Dockerfile](https://github.com/meteorhacks/meteord/blob/c3b448d43fa5d741a811c02600a95173b0c7d26d/base/Dockerfile#L10).

It checks for the presence of:

- `/bundle` folder, or
- `/built_app`, or
- `$BUNDLE_URL`

If your `counter` demo `Dockerfile` didn't populate `/bundle` or `/built_app` folders, then you need to make sure you are defining [`ENV BUNDLE_URL` with the right url](https://github.com/meteorhacks/meteord/blob/c3b448d43fa5d741a811c02600a95173b0c7d26d/README.md#21-from-the-web).

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me Vonc. 

Whats the best way to specify the /bundle folder? I tried using a url to the  file in the form 'file:///home/USERNAME/app/bundle/ and that didnt work.

Comment: @Checko As metioned in the link in my answer (https://github.com/meteorhacks/meteord/blob/c3b448d43fa5d741a811c02600a95173b0c7d26d/README.md#21-from-the-web) this bundle url references are tar.gz which represents a compressed archive of the app.

Comment: @VonC, i am following the link abobe, it works well with /bundle folder but not with a bundle url, where should the url be from?

Comment: @fay Not sure: can you ask a new question illustrating what you are trying, and how it "does not work" with an url?